# C++ 3D Matrix Using References

Tags: c++, reference

Request for a sanity check ...

I am storing a 3D matrix in a 1D array as follows:

```
double * myVector = new double[NCHANNELS*NROWS*NCOLUMNS];
```

I want to be able to access myVector using [channel][row][column] syntax, so I am creating a C++ reference:

```
double (& my3dMatrix)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS] = myVector;
```

Have I used the proper syntax here, i.e., will

```
my3dMatrix[channel][row][column]
```

return

```
*(myVector + channel*NROWS*NCOLUMNS + row*NCOLUMNS + column)?
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer, because it is a matter of personal preference, but I find that when I want to work with such ugly types, it is usually a strong sign I should begin using classes, or at least typedefs to reign in the syntax.  The likelyhood of making a mistake goes up strongly when basic syntax such as variable declarations gets murky.  Many of those mistakes become logic errors the compiler can't catch for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. But your reference initializator is missing type cast and dereference operator, it will not even compile. It should be:

```
double (& my3dMatrix)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS] =
    *(double (*)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS])myVector;
```

If you're using C++11/14, you can use this fancy syntax instead:

```
double (& my3dMatrix)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS] =
    *(decltype(&my3dMatrix))myVector;
```

---

Also, if you like to use these new C++-style casts, you can use this:

```
double (& my3dMatrix)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS] =
    *reinterpret_cast<double (*)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS]>(myVector);
```

or C++11 version:

```
double (& my3dMatrix)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS] =
    *reinterpret_cast<decltype(&my3dMatrix)>(myVector);
```

---

**Syntax explanation**

When you initialize a reference, you can only use initializator of a certain type. This type must match the type reference refers to.

```
double (& my3dMatrix)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS] = expression;
```

In this case you need `expression` to be `double [NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS]`.

`myVector` can't be used here because it's a *pointer* to array and `my3dMatrix` is a reference to an *array*. Ok, then we need to deference operator.

But `*myVector` does not work either. It's `double [NCHANNELS*NROWS*NCOLUMNS]` but we need `double [NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS]`. You want to tell the compiler than he should assume that `myVector` is pointing to another type before dereferencing it. In these cases you need a type cast.

The way you write them is `(type)expression` and `reinterpret_cast<type>(expression)`.

(First one came from C language. Second one is one of the modern C++ casts. There are 4 of them, each one have a specific purpose. C-style cast does the same and can be used instead of all 4. C++-style ones are used by some guys because they think that these casts are more readable. I personally consider them too bulky and use old one.)

So, here is your reference initialization:

```
double (& my3dMatrix)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS] =
     *       (double (*)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS])  myVector;
     ^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
dereference             C-style type cast             expression
```

Compiler trusts you and assumes that myVector is a `double (*)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS]`. After dereferncing it becomes `double [NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS]` - the type you need.

Now, about that `decltype` trick. (It was added in 2011, so old compilers don't support it.) `decltype(expression)` is replaced by the compiler with the type of `expression`. For example, `decltype(1)` means `int`. `decltype(my3dMatrix)` means `double [NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS]`. But you need another type, because you can't cast *pointer to 1D array* to *3D array*. You can cast it to *pointer to 3D array* instead. When you want address of something, you use `&`. So, you need `decltype(&my3dMatrix)`. You can assume it means `(double (&*)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS])`, but there is no such thing as pointer to reference, so it becomes just `(double (*)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS])`.

```
double (& my3dMatrix)[NCHANNELS][NROWS][NCOLUMNS] =
     *       (decltype(&my3dMatrix))  myVector;
     ^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
dereference     C-style type cast    expression
```

I hope you understood it.

Comment: @IdeaHat I rarely use it because the keyword for this cast is surprisingly long. But I'll add the info about this cast to my post.

Comment: Wow; I'm glad I asked -- I would never have figured out that syntax and would have given up when I could not fix the compiler errors. Can you explain the syntax in greater detail? Thanks.

Comment: @GregBerchin Ok, here it is. It's hard for me to write complex things in english, I hope it's ok.

Comment: It is better than OK; it is excellent and I understood it perfectly. Thank you sincerely.